# Logical AND of two pointers to loop until program break

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, logical-operators, size-t

I have code that loops through chunks of heap space, going until the program break.

```
size_t* block = heap start;
while (block&&block < (size_t*)sbrk(0)){

    block = current chunk + next chunk;
}
```

I don't understand how the logical AND (which has a value of true) meets the condition of the relational operator. The loop properly increments the address until the end of the heap, but the comparison is not making sense to me. What does this operation mean?

Comment: So, what did your find about operators and operator preceedence which you do not understand? It is a simple search away.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, especially this part "the logical AND (which has a value of true)". Is it the `block` before the `&&` that has you confused?

Comment: No, is does not always have a value of true - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: I'm asking what will the code inside of the while loop evaluate to, and how?

Comment: @yano the (block < sbrk(0)) will be true until the end when it evaluates to false, so why is the && of that result with the first block necessary? Won't the result of the relation determine the result of the whole?

Comment: see @Barmar 's answer .. he covered it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not parsing the operator precedence correctly.

```
block&&block < (size_t*)sbrk(0)
```

is equivalent to

```
block && (block < (size_t*)sbrk(0))
```

because `<` has higher precedence than `&&`.

So it's first checking that `block` is not a null pointer, and then checking if it's less than `sbrk(0)`.

Checking for null every time through the loop isn't really necessary, since the calculation inside the loop can never result in a null pointer. So this could have been written as:

```
if (block) {
    while (block < (size_t*)sbrk(0)) {
        block = current chunk + next chunk;
    }
}
```

Comment: note, I'd expect a compiler to hoist out that check anyway